# How to prevent div from scrolling out of page

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position

I have a div whose height is 500px. When I scroll the page down, I would like the div to move as the page scrolls, but I would like it to stop scrolling with the page after the 250px of the div are out of the view. The rest of the page should keep scrolling but the div should act as *fixed* after it is 250px visible on the page.

Additionally, when I scroll up, I would like the div to remain at 250px *invisible* until the user has scrolled all the way to the top (with the final 250px remaining) in which case the div should suddenly become a part of the page again and scroll with it.

I am assuming that this can be done only with JavaScript, but how?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this and are having problems, or is it your expectation that people provide your code for you?  Have you seen other sites where they do this that you can inspect their HTML/CSS/javascript to see how they do it?

Comment: I do not know how to start, nor how to google this, as I need to be descriptive in order to explain what I am looking for. I am not expecting someone else to do my job, I simply need guidance as I do not know how to achieve this (biggest issue how to know how many pixels of a div is visible on the page). No need to be an ass Mike.

Comment: It's not like this is some new ground here you are trying to look at. I am guessing you have seen this or similar on other sites before.  My suggestion that you look at how those sites are doing it is a sincere one, as you will likely learn a lot more about how you might approach the problem by looking at the example.  Outside of that, think about how you can break down the problem and work on it in smaller chunks.  Good how to mix a fixed position div, google how to make things visible on scrolling actions, etc. and start to piece a solution together.

Comment: OK, thanks for search suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, using the keywords suggested by Mike Brant up in the comments, my Google search produced some good results. It appears that the functionality I was after is called sticky div, or sticky menu, sticky footer, or likewise.

By looking at the code of those javascripts I was able to understand the concept behind it. Now, it's time to play with it and adjust to my particular needs.

Comment: how about an example?